# How do I get python 3 syntax highlighting in vim?

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, python-3.x

All the highlighting right now uses python2.6 and that makes me very sad face.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use python.vim plugin

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=790

make sure you download the 3.0 version plugin